# Why The Init Hook For Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, actions

I have a question about [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) documentation.

Why would I register a Custom Post Type in the init function as the docs suggest? Is this only if I am not using a plugin?

As I understand it, [init runs every-time WordPress runs/is-loaded](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) by the user. Doesn't this mean the site is needlessly re-registering a new post type on every visit? Why not (if building a plugin) register the post type in `require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` just when the plugin activates?

Wouldn't that also speed up the site? Or am I interpreting `init()` wrong? Surely the custom post type persists in the database somewhere so doesn't have to be called on every `init()`?

Here is the Custom Post Type example from the docs, using `init()`:

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Products' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`register_post_type` function should be executed every time a WP request is made. Default post types don't have this requirement. You can use your code as is, in MU plugin. Just create a `.PHP` file with this code, and place it in `mu-plugins` sub-folder of `wp-content`. You don't need to provide any standard plugin headers.

Comment: But... why? Why do I need to re-register on every request? Will it disappear if I don't call it? Isn't this the sort of thing that should persist...

Comment: Only the content, and the name of CPT are stored in database. Registration of CPT is needed to build admin menu items for that CPT ( labels, and other menu related things ). If you don't register a CPT, then you will not have access to it.

Comment: If the CPT is going to be private and not on the admin menu anyway is it viable to prepopulate it using the plugin activation hook and then query it later?

Comment: It does not matter. WP knows everything about default post types, but knows nothing about CPT, until is been registered. This how it's been designed. I agree with your concept, but for now, this is how it's done.

Comment: Hmm... okay, just making sure I wasn't completely wrong. :)

Comment: You’re assuming that registering a post type is a more expensive operation than it really is. Keep in mind that registering a post type does not store anything in the database.

Answer (score 6):

> Surely the custom post type persists in the database somewhere so
>   doesn't have to be called on every init()?

No, it's not. Why would it need to be? A custom post type is a handful of variables that WordPress will use to set up the UI for data saved with that post type in the database.

If the data were going to change frequently, and the changes needed to be persistent, then storing in the database would be necessary, but post types do not change after development.

Considering that, saving the settings for the post type in the database would only *hurt* performance, as WordPress would need to query the database just to get the settings for registered post types on every page load, which is slower than just executing the registration code each time (which remember is just a handful of variables).

The most expensive part of registering a post type is generating its rewrite rules, which is why those *are* stored in the database, and the rewrite rules *should* be flushed on the activation and deactivation hooks.